# Python Permutation with Limits and Directionality

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have a problem that I can't get my head around, so I can only give you pseudocode at best.

```
lista=(a,b,c)
listb=(a1,b1,c1,d1,a2,b2,c2,d2,a3,b3,c3,d3)
```

I need a way to limit the results of the permutations of listsb to the following criteria:

A tuple of only items contained in lista

The order of lista needs to be retained

The permutations can only look to the right

lista and list b can be any length

For example:

Acceptable:

a1,b1,c1

a2,b3,c3

Unacceptable:

a1,b1,d1

a2,b1,c3

b2,a2,c3

Any ideas you have will be most appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about calling those "permutations", since it seems like you only want one-of-each combination.

Probably most straightforward to just write your own recursive generator.  I used string operations and `startswith` to determine the association between `lista` and `listb`; you can do that however you want if you have different objects.

```
lista=('a','b','c')
listb=('a1','b1','c1','d1','a2','b2','c2','d2','a3','b3','c3','d3')

def gen_combos(li, keepers, builder=tuple()):
    if not keepers:
        yield builder
    else:
        for i,x in enumerate(li):
            if x.startswith(keepers[0]):
                for combo in gen_combos(li[i+1:], keepers[1:], builder + (x,)):
                    yield combo
```

demo:

```
list(gen_combos(listb, lista))
Out[40]: 
[('a1', 'b1', 'c1'),
 ('a1', 'b1', 'c2'),
 ('a1', 'b1', 'c3'),
 ('a1', 'b2', 'c2'),
 ('a1', 'b2', 'c3'),
 ('a1', 'b3', 'c3'),
 ('a2', 'b2', 'c2'),
 ('a2', 'b2', 'c3'),
 ('a2', 'b3', 'c3'),
 ('a3', 'b3', 'c3')]
```